# Kinetic.js Animating Multiple groups that contain a shape and text

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

I'm new to Kinetic.js. I am trying to create a series of randomly moving groups, each containing one star and a title. Here is the current sketch: http://jsfiddle.net/dCw9e/.

I can't figure out why each group object has a unique set of boundaries in the animation. Can anyone shed any light on what I am missing here? Why aren't the boundaries for each group the same? i.e. the boundaries of the parent container.

This is the animation:

var anim = new Kinetic.Animation(function(frame) {

```
newtime = frame.time;

// Acceleration due to gravity via time delay (chunks miliseconds)
if((newtime - oldtime) > framerate) { // every N milliseconds... (this emulated a frame rate)
    oldtime = newtime;

    var angularSpeed = Math.PI / 2;
    var angleDiff = [];


    var stage = MilestonesGame.stage;
    var stageKids = stage.getChildren();
    var starsLayer = stageKids[1];
    var stars = [];
    stars = starsLayer.getChildren();
    //console.log(stars[1].getX());

    for(var n= 0; n < groups.length; n++){
        angleDiff[n] = frame.timeDiff * angularSpeed / 10000 * rotDir[n];
    }   


    for(var j = 0; j < groups.length; j++) {



    /* Bounce stars off all stage parameter boundaries */

    // floor boundary
    if(groups[j].getY() > floor) {groups[j].setY(floor);}
    if(groups[j].getY() == floor) {

     $(window).resize(_.debounce(function(){
        floor = MilestonesGame.stage.getHeight()-7;
     }, 300));

        yvel[j] *= -1;

    }

    //Ceiling boundary
    if(groups[j].getY() < cieling){groups[j].setY(cieling);}
    if(groups[j].getY() == cieling){

        yvel[j] *= -1;

    }
    // right wall
    if(groups[j].getX() > rightwall) {groups[j].setX(rightwall);}
    if(groups[j].getX() == rightwall) {

        $(window).resize(_.debounce(function(){
            rightwall = MilestonesGame.stage.getWidth()-7;
        }, 300));

        xvel[j] *= -1;
    }
    // left wall
    if(groups[j].getX() < leftwall) {groups[j].setX(leftwall);}
    if(groups[j].getX() == leftwall) {

        xvel[j] *= -1;
    }

    groups[j].setX(groups[j].getX() + xvel[j]);                                 
    groups[j].setY(groups[j].getY() + yvel[j]);
    //stars[i].rotate(angleDiff[i]);
    }
}
```

}, this.starsLayer);
anim.start();

Thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 2):

The origin [x,y] of any group defaults to being [0,0] relative to its parent.

In your case, every groups parent is the stage.

So all your groups origins--their x/y, are relative to the stage.

A few observations...

**Take your resizing event handler outside of any loops (bad practice if inside loops).**

```
// resizing handler -- never put this in a loop!

$(window).resize(_.debounce(function(){
    rightwall = MilestonesGame.stage.getWidth();
    floor = MilestonesGame.stage.getHeight();
}, 300));
```

**Let your boundaries be full-sized so you can easily resize your stars later**

```
// boundaries -- leave boundaries full width/height
// which lets you resize each star later

var leftwall = 0;
var rightwall = MilestonesGame.stage.getWidth();
var floor = MilestonesGame.stage.getHeight();
var cieling = 0;
```

**Your boundary hit tests can be refactored like this for performance and clarity:**

```
// Bounce stars off all stage parameter boundaries 

    for(var j = 0; j < groups.length; j++) {


    // temp save often used array references in vars

    var group=groups[j];
    var x=group.getX();
    var y=group.getY();
    var r=group.getOuterRadius();

    // ceiling boundary

    if(y-r<=cieling) {
        y=cieling+r;
        yvel[j] *= -1;
    }

    // floor boundary

    if(y+r>=floor) {
        y=floor-r;
        yvel[j] *= -1;
    }

    // left boundary

    if(x-r<=leftwall) {
        x=leftwall+r;
        xvel[j] *= -1;
    }

    // left and right boundary

    if(x+r>=rightwall) {
        x=rightwall-r;
        xvel[j] *= -1;
    }

    // move this star
    group.setX(x + xvel[j]);                                    
    group.setY(y + yvel[j]);

    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! When you say that "all your groups origins--their x/y, are relative to the stage" am I correct in assuming you mean that each group's 0, 0, point should be aligned, to the 0, 0 point of the stage? It's counter-intuitive for me, because each group's 0, 0 point is strangely offset by the difference in each group's x, y attribute...can't quite wrap my head around why this is happening...any thoughts?

Comment: Yes, groups[0]{x:0,y:0} is positioned at stage[0,0]. So your groups[0]{x:16,y:16} is at stage[16,16].  Anything inside groups[0] will start at stage[16,16] plus their own x,y.  For example, a rect inside group[0] with that rect having its own x:20,y:30 will be at stage[16+20,16+30].

Comment: Ok, so, in my animation when I call:

Comment: oops, when I call,    groups[j].setX(groups[j].getX() + xvel[j]);         
groups[j].setY(groups[j].getY() + yvel[j]);, shouldn't that move the groups within the boundary of the stage So that each of their  'cielings' is the stage's?